# CSS3 Progress Bar - Jagged stripes

Tags: css, progress-bar

I'm trying to code progress-bar like this.

http://www.red-team-design.com/stylish-css3-progress-bars


(the first one, with stripes)

### Problem explanation

When I edited my Progress-bar (my own colors, width, removed animation etc.) it doesn't look smooth, it looks jagged.

Here's screenshot:

[image]

Here's live preview:

http://tvojaskola.eu/test.html

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-2"><div class="progress-bar blue stripes">
    <span style="width: 60%"></span>
</div> 
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.progress-bar {
  background-color: rgba(236,236,236,1);
    height: 25px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;            
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
}
.progress-bar span {
  float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;   
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
}
.blue span {
    background-color: #224b8f;   
}
.stripes span {
    -webkit-background-size: 10px 10px;
    -moz-background-size: 10px 10px;
    background-size: 10px 10px;         
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,
                        color-stop(.25, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1)), color-stop(.25, transparent),
                        color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1)),
                        color-stop(.75, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1)), color-stop(.75, transparent),
                        to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 50%, rgba(236, 236, 236, 1) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);            
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks, guys.

Comment: I know this entry is 4 years old, however I found this on top of the google results when I was looking for a quick solution on this issue, so here is what helped me further: https://catalin.red/dist/uploads/2011/11/css3-slick-progress-bars-demo.html#

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [repeating-linear-gradient](http://24ways.org/2011/css3-patterns-explained/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the bootstrap progress bars

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html

I think they even have javascript you can use to make it move on its own